# One liner for using xargs to grep output of one command on a search text produced by other command

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xargs

I am trying to accomplish the following in one line:

```
<command> | xargs -I {} grep {} <(other command)>
```

I have a Kubernetes cluster which is running Redis and many other applications. I want to find out which applications (pods in this case) are connected to Redis.

This can be broken down in two steps.

- Getting the list of IPs connected to Redis.
- Get the pod names that holds those IPs.

I got the list of IPs with the following command:

```
$ kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
10.52.1.194
10.52.1.91
10.52.2.44
10.52.3.223
127.0.0.1
```

And I can also get the pod names with the following command:

```
$ grep -f test.txt <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
app1              1/1     Running     0          9d      10.52.1.91    node-8    <none>           <none>
app2              2/2     Running     0          79d     10.52.2.44    node-14   <none>           <none>
app3              2/2     Running     2          79d     10.52.1.194   node-11   <none>           <none>
app4              1/1     Running     0          5d10h   10.52.3.223   node-30   <none>           <none>
```

I want to accomplish both of these in one line. I tried the following:

```
$ kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' sort | uniq | xargs -t -I{} grep {} <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

it prints the following commands (that should be performed) but only performs the the first command:

```
grep 10.52.1.194 /dev/fd/63
app3              2/2     Running     2          79d     10.52.1.194   node-11   <none>           <none>
grep 127.0.0.1 /dev/fd/63
grep 10.52.1.91 /dev/fd/63
grep 10.52.2.44 /dev/fd/63
grep 10.52.3.223 /dev/fd/63
```

How can I accomplish this in one line. Also, I am aware that I can give an `name` to each client that is connecting to Redis but it requires changing the application code which I can't do right now.

**Edit:**

The one-liner given by me actually partially works as in it only performs the first `grep ...` instead of all the `grep ...` commands. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit2:**

My hypothesis that only the first grep command works is that somehow after the first grep command, `/dev/fd/63` probably points to a non-existing or empty file. Also, the following command works for some reason. Can anyone explain?

```
$ kubectl exec -t redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort -u | xargs -t -I{} bash -c 'grep -w {} <(kubectl get pods -o wide)'
bash -c grep -w 10.52.1.194 <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
app3                 2/2     Running     2          80d     10.52.1.194   node-11   <none>           <none>
bash -c grep -w 10.52.1.91 <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
app1                 1/1     Running     0          10d     10.52.1.91    node-8    <none>           <none>
bash -c grep -w 10.52.2.44 <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
app2                 2/2     Running     0          80d     10.52.2.44    node-14   <none>           <none>
bash -c grep -w 10.52.3.223 <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
app4                 1/1     Running     0          6d10h   10.52.3.223   node-30   <none>           <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one :

```
grep -f <(kubectl exec -t redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq) <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

If you have problems, trouble-shoot with this command first :

```
cat <(kubectl exec -t redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq)
cat <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply:

```
kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2 | awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq | grep -f - <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

Or same:

```
kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list |
    tail -n +2 |
    awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' |
    sort |
    uniq |
    grep -f - <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

Note 1: This is still one line, you could *cut'n paste* and even drop *newlines*. Just easier to re-read.

Note 2: `sort | uniq` could be simplified by `sort -u`:

```
kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list |
    tail -n +2 |
    awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' |
    sort -u |
    grep -f - <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

But you could event write this:

```
grep -f <(
    kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list |
        tail -n +2 |
        awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' |
        sort -u
  ) <(
    kubectl get pods -o wide
  )
```

Could be re-writted in two lines:

```
grep -f <(kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list |
  tail -n +2|awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort -u) <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

or

```
grep -f <(kubectl exec -it redis -- redis-cli -a <redis-auth> client list | tail -n +2|awk -F '[:= ]' '{ print $4 }' | sort -u) <(kubectl get pods -o wide)
```

Comment: The first command in this answer gives me: `grep: -: No such file or directory`

Comment: Strange! You could try: `grep /dev/stdin` instead of `grep -`

Comment: `grep /dev/stdin` works. Thanks. Can you find any mistake in the original command that I posted in the question? As I've added in the Edit section, my command works for the first grep but not for any other grep statements. Any idea why?

Comment: xargs will *transform* stdin into  *separated arguments* passed to `grep` command. It's not what you try to do...

Comment: From what I know, `xargs` will take the input, separate it at `\n` by default (unless explicitly told to delimit at null character) and run the `grep` command for each of that input. In my case, it's only running it for the first input argument and ignoring all the rest and I do not understand why that's the case because the commands are exactly the same (all grep commands). Is it because `/dev/fd/63` only points to non-empty file for the first argument?